# как сделать select с двумя case

Tags: sql-server

сделал запрос, но хотел бы, чтобы сумма отображалась, если ноль не был показан, этот запрос сделан но только отдельно, я не могу добавить к этому запросу, как не быть?

запрос который мне нужен в маем запросе

```
case when [Summa]=0 then null else round(a.Summa,2) end as Summa
```

мой запрос

```
SELECT
    [a].[id],
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), [a].[Date], 104) AS [Data],
    [j].[Login],
    [b].[Name] AS [NameAgency],
    [c].[Name] AS [NamePosition],
    [d].[Name] AS [NameOperatonsType],
    [e].[Name] AS [NamePartnerType],
    [f].[Name] AS [NameType],
    [g].[Name] AS [NamePartners],
    [h].[name] AS [NameBank],
    [i].[name] AS [NameCurrency],
    CASE       
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 2 THEN
            '0'
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Prikhod],
    CASE
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 1 THEN
            '0'
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Raskhod],
    [a].[Comment]
FROM
    [Operations] AS [a] LEFT JOIN
    [Agency] AS [b] ON [a].[AgencyID] = [b].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [Position] AS [c] ON [a].[PositionID] = [c].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [OperatonsType] AS [d] ON [a].[OperType] = [d].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [PartnerType] AS [e] ON [a].[ParentID] = [e].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [NameType] AS [f] ON [a].[NameTypeID] = [f].[ID] LEFT JOIN
    [Partners] AS [g] ON [a].[PartnerID] = [g].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Bank] AS [h] ON [a].[BankID] = [h].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Currency] AS [i] ON [a].[CurrencyID] = [i].[id] LEFT JOIN
    [Users] AS [j] ON [a].[UserID] = [j].[ID]
WHERE
    [a].[Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
ORDER BY
    [a].[id] DESC;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу заменить 0 на NULL для столбцов Приход и Расход

Comment: А почему вместо case не использовать If?

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Потому, что case - стандарт SQL, if - нет. Разве не аргумент?

Comment: @0xdb а чем грозит использование IIF вместо CASE?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Несовместимостью при миграции, больше вроде ничем.

Comment: Ну так и пишите     `CASE       
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 2 THEN
            NULL
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Prikhod]`...

Comment: @Akina а там просто, если посмотреть на вывод, у id, которые не попадают под изначальное условие ставится 0. Я так понял, там при ID, не попадающих под условие, тоже нужен null, хотя id на выводе и берутся из [a]

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` нужен, когда у вас больше ветвлений, чем одно. Иначе его можно заменить просто одним `IFом`

```
CASE       
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 2 THEN
            '0'
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Prikhod],
    CASE
        WHEN [d].[ID] = 1 THEN
            '0'
        ELSE
            [a].[Summa]
    END AS [Raskhod]
```

Заменить на:

```
IIF([d].[ID] = 2 or [a].[Summa] = 0, NULL, [a].[Summa]) as [Prikhod],
IIF([d].[ID] = 1 or [a].[Summa] = 0, NULL, [a].[Summa]) as [Raskhod]
```

Comment: сделал так но есть ошибка "Incorrect syntax near '=' "

Comment: @ariana поставьте числа в кавычки